# test automation ideas specific numbers and you can't repeat any number

Tags: excel, automation, ui-automation, selenium-java

I am writing an automation script and I have a number IMO it's somehow unique and can't be repeated, so I need new number each time I repeat this from excel sheet, I can add dozens of unused numbers. but each time I run the script it will start from the beginning.

> Example IMO = 823947,912389,1728462,9899236.
> Each time I run the script it will start with 823947. I don't want the automation script to repeat or to start from the beginning. I want it to be smart enough to know that this record is already used before and start from the unused one.

Is there any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: do a find() or match(), both return a value if the target exists...